# What field's value of a partially initialized object could a reader thread see according to Java Memory Model?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, java-memory-model

More specifically, assuming an object is partially initialized and a field x is initialized to null by the object's constructor, is it possible that some other thread reading this partially initialized object can see any other value than null?

If I understand it correctly, there's no guarantee in Java Memory Model itself that the value will always be null in such case. The question is: considering CPU caches and JVM memory architecture, should it be reasonably expected that the value could be not null?

Comment: If you adhere to the conventions and suggestions on class design (e.g. don't call potentially overridden methods in your constructors, use propery synchronization/concurrency handling methods) that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I know. I was just curious what's the worst that can happen - the default value or any random value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible – there is no guarantee that an object which has been initialised in a constructor by one thread will be correctly read by another thread. The Java memory model allows the compiler to reorder statements within the constructor so long at the reordering does not effect the the state of the object on completion of the initialisation.

Another thread can obtain a reference to the object after it has been allocated in memory but before the constructor has completed and may read an uninitialised value.

You need to protect access to such variables using the synchronised keyword or by using synchronized collections.

See: [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

Comment: That's correct. What I'm wondering is whether "an uninitialised value" means always null (for reference fields) or any could be any random value? In other words, if I don't initialize a reference field and another thread reads partially initialized object, is it guaranteed that the reader thread sees null?

Comment: @pzieba it is aways zero/false/null as soon as the constructor is called, otherwise it would be possible to get a corrupt reference and crash the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

By default, reference member variables are initialized to null. If the constructor had set the field to a non-null value, then it'd have been possible for other threads to see a null or non-null value. But if the constructor also is setting the value as null (which seems redundant in a simple scenario), then it is NOT possible for other threads to see any value other than null (the only value the field ever had is null, so there is no question of seeing any other value)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! One more question: does the guarantee comes form JMM itself or it's just JMV feature?

Comment: The fact that reference member variables are defaulted to null (even before the constructor runs) is specified in the JLS. Examples in JMM documentation talk about scenarios where fields within partially constructed objects may appear to hold their initial/default value (null/0/false), when in-fact the constructor assigns them a different value. There is no case where a thread cannot even see the initial default value of null/0/false. E.g. refer to the first example here - https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/TSM03-J.+Do+not+publish+partially+initialized+objects